# Dropzone JS not working with multiple input Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, dropzone.js

i have multiple input, textarea and select i need multiple image upload so i try dropzone js and in controller request there is no file

i use `autoProcessQueue: false` and its not working but if i don't use it upload but i don't get data in request file

Problem is how can i get request file from dropzone

this is dropzone script

```
 <script>
Dropzone.options.dropzone = 
{
    // The configuration we've talked about above
    url: "{{ route('product.store') }}",
    headers: {
    'x-csrf-token': "{{ csrf_token() }}",
    },
    // autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 100,
    maxFiles: 100,

    // The setting up of the dropzone
    init: function() {
    var myDropzone = this;
    var formData = new FormData();
    // First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.
    $("#prodcutCreate").click(function (e){
        // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        myDropzone.processQueue();
    });
    
    // Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead
    // of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
    this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {
    // Gets triggered when the form is actually being sent.
    // Hide the success button or the complete form.

    // formData.append("name", $("#name").val());
    // formData.append("slug", $("#slug").val());
    // formData.append("description", $("#description").val());
    // formData.append("ideal_for", $("#ideal_for").val());
    // formData.append("main_ingredients", $("#main_ingredients").val());
    // formData.append("gender_id", $("#gender_id").val());
    // formData.append("brand_id", $("#brand_id").val());
    // formData.append("categories", $("#categories").val());
    });
    this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
    // Gets triggered when the files have successfully been sent.
    // Redirect user or notify of success.
    console.log('success');
    console.log(files);
    console.log(response);
    });
    this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
    // Gets triggered when there was an error sending the files.
    // Maybe show form again, and notify user of error
    console.log(false);
    console.log(files);
    console.log(response);
    });
    }
}
```

this is controller i dd the request but no file

```
public function store(Request $request){dd($request); }
```

this is form i have other input fileds too

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('product.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="col-span-4 dropzone" id="dropzone"></div>
```

this is from $request

```
files: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag 
{#46 
    #parameters: []
}
```

*thanks*

Comment: Have you checked the network tab on the payload passed to the server?

Comment: yes i have checked that there is 
file[0]: (binary)